# Powershell script is removing items

Tags: powershell

Im in the proces of learning powershell, so its all new for me.
I came across this post: https://www.thelazyadministrator.com/2020/01/26/deploy-intune-applications-with-powershell-and-azure-blob-storage/
I striped down the local part of the location because i want to rely solely on the blob storage.

I tried using this for office pro plus but it does not seem to work.
What it currently does: it downloads the required zip from our blob storage and puts it inside folder in %appdata%, it then starts to extract them.
When nearing the extraction proces it cuts out and starts removing all the already extracted files.

I cannot seem to wrap my head around this problem..
here is my current itteration of the script:

```
param (
    [System.String]$ZipSourceFiles      = "url to zip",
    [system.string]$IntuneProgramDir    = "$env:APPDATA\Intune",
    [System.String]$FullEXEDir          = "$IntuneProgramDir\Intune\setup.exe",
    [System.String]$ZipLocation         = "$IntuneProgramDir\office.zip"
)
    #Start download of the source files from Azure Blob to the network cache location
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $ZipSourceFiles -Destination $ZipLocation

    #Check to see if the local cache directory is present
    If ((Test-Path -Path $IntuneProgramDir) -eq $False)
    {
        #Create the local cache directory
        New-Item -ItemType Directory $IntuneProgramDir -Force -Confirm:$False
    }

    #Copy the binaries from the network cache to the local computer cache
    Copy-Item $TempNetworkZip -Destination $IntuneProgramDir  -Force

    #Extract the install binaries
    Expand-Archive -Path $ZipLocation -DestinationPath $IntuneProgramDir -Force

    #Install the program
    Start-Process "$FullEXEDir" -ArgumentList " /S /v/qn"
Else {
    #Check to see if the local cache directory is present
    If ((Test-Path -Path $IntuneProgramDir) -eq $False)
    {
        #Create the local cache directory
        New-Item -ItemType Directory $IntuneProgramDir -Force -Confirm:$False
    }

    #Copy the installer binaries from the network cache location to the local computer cache
    Copy-Item $TempNetworkZip -Destination $IntuneProgramDir  -Force

    #Extract the install binaries
    Expand-Archive -Path $ZipLocation -DestinationPath $IntuneProgramDir -Force

    #Install the program
    Start-Process "$FullEXEDir" -ArgumentList " /S /v/qn"
}
```

Comment: The `param` section seems to be adapted correctly however there are syntax errors in the script body (something went wrong in `copy/paste`, e.g. an orphaned `else` keyword). IMHO the script isn't optimally written at _thelazyadministrator_… ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for optimization of the final _running_ version.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need if-else here. Try:

```
  param (
    [System.String]$ZipSourceFiles      = "url to zip",
    [system.string]$IntuneProgramDir    = "$env:APPDATA\Intune",
    [System.String]$FullEXEDir          = "$IntuneProgramDir\Intune\setup.exe",
    [System.String]$ZipLocation         = "$IntuneProgramDir\office.zip"
)

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $ZipSourceFiles -Destination $ZipLocation

 #Check to see if the local cache directory is present
    If ((Test-Path -Path $IntuneProgramDir) -eq $False)
    {
        #Create the local cache directory
        New-Item -ItemType Directory $IntuneProgramDir -Force -Confirm:$False
    }


    #Extract the install binaries
    Expand-Archive -Path $ZipLocation -DestinationPath $IntuneProgramDir -Force

    #Install the program
    Start-Process "$FullEXEDir" -ArgumentList " /S /v/qn"
```